# How do you change the ng-model attribute of an element (and have it work)?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-module, jqlite

I have an input with an `ng-model` attribute set to "search.name"

HTML

```
Search: 
<span id="searchName"> titles </span> | <span id="searchSpecies"> species </span>:

<input type="text" data-ng-model="search.name" />
```

How can I change this attribute when another element is clicked, like a link or a button, **and have my filters work with the updated attribute?** Right now even if I have updated the attribute, the filters act as if it hasn't updated.

This is how I update the attribute:

SCRIPT

```
$("#searchName").click(function() {
     $("input").attr("data-ng-model", "recipesearch.name");
});
$("#searchSpecies").click(function() {
         $("input").attr("data-ng-model", "recipesearch.species");
});
```

Is there a better way to do this perhaps with a directive?

Comment: Angular has to compile your html and create watches on all your binding. If you are changing your binding expression you need to compile the html element again to update the binding. I am not sure how to do it exactly.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand the problem correctly, you have a form where data is filtered based on what is typed in the input box.  But you also have other links that can change the search for you automatically, perhaps a list of "common search values".

What I would do is outlined in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tpeiffer/gHcwg/%20Fiddle).

Basically I suggest using ng-click on your link or button to update the value being searched on.

Example:

Markup

```
 <a href="#" ng-click="changeSearchTo('Cat')">Cat</a>
```

Controller

```
 $scope.changeSearchTo = function (searchCriteria) {
     $scope.search = {
         name: searchCriteria
     };
 };
```

If I did not understand your question, I apologize.

-Thad

Comment: Thad, no need to apologize! I appreciate your help. Unfortunately, that isn't quite what I had in mind. This solution changes the value entered into the input box, but I want to instead change the value of `ng-model` within the HTML. For example, change `ng-model="search.name"` to `ng-model="search.ingredients"`.  So `search.name` changes to `search.ingredients`. I was able to make this attribute change using jQuery, but it still acts as if the value is `search.name`. I think it has something to do with what @Chandermani said above about recompiling..

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at [$setViewValue](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angModel.NgModelController#%24setViewValue)

> "This method should be called from within a DOM event handler. For
>   example input or select directives call it.
>
> It internally calls all parsers and if resulted value is valid,
>   updates the model and calls all registered change listeners."

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your code inside `$(document).ready()` as below

and also make sure you have added link to jQuery library

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/LBRYM/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#searchName").click(function () {
        $("input").attr("data-ng-model", "recipesearch.name");
    });
    $("#searchSpecies").click(function () {
        $("input").attr("data-ng-model", "recipesearch.species");
    });
});
```

Comment: Ah, okay. This does change the attribute. However even when the attribute has been changed, angular is still treating the attribute field as the originally placed attribute, `recipesearch.name`. subsequently it has no effect on my angular filters.